# Read in nested JSON from zipfile via URL [Python]

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to read in text file from EIA that is zipped. I have been able to get the file downloaded, unzipped, and converted to a string that is I believe JSON formatted but can not seem to convert it into a DataFrame. Help is greatly appreciated.

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
import io
import zipfile
import json

url_data='https://api.eia.gov/bulk/PET.zip'
r = requests.get(url_data)
with zipfile.ZipFile(io.BytesIO(r.content), mode="r") as archive:
    archive.printdir()
    text = archive.read("PET.txt") .decode(encoding="utf-8")
```

Comment: Have you opened this file to see what it contains? Why are you using `.decode(encoding="utf-8")` anyway? Python strings are already Unicode. The only thing that call can do is mangle any non-Latin text

Comment: The file is a text file that I believe looks like a JSON. Here is the top few lines {"series_id":"PET.EMM_EPM0_PTE_SMA_DPG.W","name":"Massachusetts All Grades All Formulations Retail Gasoline Prices, Weekly","units":"Dollars per Gallon","f":"W","unitsshort":"$\/gal","description":"Massachusetts All Grades All Formulations Retail Gasoline Prices","copyright":"None","source":"EIA, U.S. Energy Information Administration","iso3166":"USA-MA","geography":"USA-MA","start":"20030526","end":"20220418","last_updated":"2022-04-18T19:29:14-04:00","data":[["20220418",4.132],["20220411",4.146],

Comment: Looking at the file, the text is JSON formatted. I've tried to use df = pd.read_json(text, lines=True) and it worked like a charm. 
It's always good to print and see what type of data are you dealing with.

Comment: Pandas can read compressed files without problem. That file isn't a valid JSON file though, it contains one JSON document per line. A JSON document *can't* have multiple roots. Writing one doc per line is a common technique to store a large amount of data because it allows reading one line at a time

Comment: The df = pd.read_json(text, lines=True) worked like a charm! Seemed I tried everything under the sun but didn't know the "lines=True" part. Much appreciated!

Comment: You need to see what the data looks like even if nothing goes wrong. You can use `nrow` with `lines` to load only a few lines at a time. That's the main benefit of this format

Answer (score 0):

To read this file use :

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_json(path_to_zip,lines=True)
```

`df` contains all rows

```
>>> df.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 188297 entries, 0 to 188296
Data columns (total 19 columns):
 #   Column              Non-Null Count   Dtype  
---  ------              --------------   -----  
 0   series_id           174220 non-null  object 
 1   name                188297 non-null  object 
 2   units               174220 non-null  object 
 3   f                   174220 non-null  object 
 4   unitsshort          174220 non-null  object 
 5   description         174220 non-null  object
 6   copyright           174220 non-null  object
 7   source              174220 non-null  object
 8   iso3166             134979 non-null  object
 9   geography           161968 non-null  object
 10  start               174220 non-null  float64
 11  end                 174220 non-null  float64
 12  last_updated        174220 non-null  object
 13  data                174220 non-null  object
 14  geography2          105177 non-null  object
 15  category_id         14077 non-null   float64
 16  parent_category_id  14077 non-null   float64
 17  notes               14077 non-null   object
 18  childseries         14077 non-null   object
```

[read_json](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_json.html) can already read compressed JSON files. This isn't a JSON file though, it contains one JSON document per line. You can read such files with the `lines` parameter.

In a JSON document there can be only one root, either an object or array. This means the *entire* document must be read into memory before it can be parsed. This causes severe problems with large files like this one, or when an application wants to append JSON documents (eg records) to an existing file. The entire file would have to be read and written at once.

To overcome this, it's common to store one unindented JSON document per line. This way, to add a new document all the code has to do is append a new line. To read a subset of the lines, an application only needs to seek to the first newline after an offset and read the next N lines.

`read_csv` can read a subset of such files when `lines = True` through the `nrows` parameter:

```
>>> df2=pd.read_json(r"C:\Users\pankan\Downloads\PET.zip",lines=True,nrows=100)
>>> df2.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 100 entries, 0 to 99
Data columns (total 14 columns):
 #   Column        Non-Null Count  Dtype
---  ------        --------------  -----
 0   series_id     100 non-null    object
 1   name          100 non-null    object
 2   units         100 non-null    object
 3   f             100 non-null    object
 4   unitsshort    100 non-null    object
 5   description   100 non-null    object
 6   copyright     100 non-null    object
 7   source        100 non-null    object
 8   iso3166       67 non-null     object
 9   geography     100 non-null    object
 10  start         100 non-null    int64
 11  end           100 non-null    int64
 12  last_updated  100 non-null    object
 13  data          100 non-null    object
```